# How to get Japanese input working on Loki?

Tags: release-loki, ibus, fcitx

I have been trying to setup Japanese input on elementary. After many hours of Googling around and installing and uninstalling packages I have made it work with IBus and the Anthy input method. The way I made it work was by installing anthy and Ibus and then running `im-config` and selecting IBus as the input method. Unfortunately, once I do this I can no longer type at all on Slingshot. Everything except Slingshot seems fine thus far.

I also tried setting things up with fcitx but to get that working I had to remove IBus completely which seemed to eliminate some important packages, some stuff related to System Settings, so I decided not to use that method. Plus fcitx added a new icon on the wingpanel which is quite ugly.

Furthermore, with both IBus and fcitx, mozc didn't work, which works alright on Ubuntu 16.04. This is bad because I prefor mozc to Anthy.

I really want to use Elementary, but I need Japanese input to work and I can not get a satisfactory setup working.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed nimf for Korean input and it works like a charm. I don't use Japanese but nimf does support Japanese with anthy so give it a try! First install nimf with sudo apt-get install nimf , then run im-config -n nimf , then reboot. Next, run nimf-settings and set up your hotkey to switch input methods. Reboot again and it should work! Just remember that you might need to install gnome-language-selector ( sudo apt-get install gnome-language-selector ) and switch the Japanese input to nimf since ibus is already installed. Hope it works! :)

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Unfortunately the support for anthy in nimf is still in alpha stage, so it doesn't work very well. But I will keep using this for now, until I can find a better setup.

Comment: You should use the new version here: http://cogniti.github.io/nimf/download/

Comment: But there still are some problems with it, such as I can't type "人" by typing "jin" with Anthy.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get mozc with fcitx working by following [this article](http://balloon-aka-fu-sen.tumblr.com/post/150211222217/elementary-os-040-loki) which is in Japanese, but it is quite easy to follow, specially with the commands and the screenshots.